Why is SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privilige deleted every 10 minutes in AWS RDS (MYSQL)?
I'm using AWS RDS, and in my MYSQL (>8.0) database, the SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN permission for all users is deleted every 10 minutes. It wasn't deleted originally, but it's suddenly being deleted, and I'd like to find out the reason.
rds parameter groups?
